# import and append data

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to import tables from Excel to Access and keep the relationships between those tables.

I have some empty tables in Access that are connected to eachother with foreign keys, and what I basically want to do is fill those tables with data from Access without losing any relationship. E.g. the table "ProductsTests" will still inherit the foreign keys of the table "Products" when data is added.

What do you think is the best way to do it? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you just import the Excel file into a different table, and then use an SQL query to add the data to the desired table, there's no problem (as long as you import in the right order so you don't violate referential integrity, and don't do one to one relationships).

Overwriting a table with relationships is somewhat more difficult, this is from one of my projects:

Add the following code to a module:

```
'This function makes a duplicate of the provided relation
Public Function DuplicateRelation(SourceRelation As Relation) As Relation
    Set DuplicateRelation = CurrentDb.CreateRelation(SourceRelation.NAME, SourceRelation.Table, SourceRelation.ForeignTable)
    DuplicateRelation.Attributes = SourceRelation.Attributes
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fldLoop As Field
    Do While i < SourceRelation.Fields.Count
        Set fldLoop = DuplicateRelation.CreateField(SourceRelation.Fields(i).NAME)
        fldLoop.ForeignName = SourceRelation.Fields(i).ForeignName
        DuplicateRelation.Fields.Append fldLoop
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Function

'This function creates a collection containing duplicates of all relations involving strTablename, and then deletes those relations 
Public Function DeleteRelationshipsCreateBackup(strTablename As String) As Collection
    Dim ReturnCollection As Collection
    Set ReturnCollection = New Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim o As Integer
    Do While i <= (CurrentDb.Relations.Count - 1)
        Select Case strTablename 
            Case Is = CurrentDb.Relations(i).Table
                ReturnCollection.Add DuplicateRelation(CurrentDb.Relations(i))
                o = o + 1
                CurrentDb.Relations.Delete CurrentDb.Relations(i).NAME
            Case Is = CurrentDb.Relations(i).ForeignTable
                ReturnCollection.Add DuplicateRelation(CurrentDb.Relations(i))
                o = o + 1
                CurrentDb.Relations.Delete CurrentDb.Relations(i).NAME
            Case Else
                i = i + 1
        End Select
    Loop
    Set DeleteRelationshipsCreateBackup = ReturnCollection
End Function

'This function restores the duplicate created by DeleteRelationshipsCreateBackup
Public Sub RestoreRelationBackup(collRelationBackup As Collection)
    Dim relBackup As Variant
    If collRelationBackup.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    For Each relBackup In collRelationBackup
        CurrentDb.Relations.Append relBackup
    Next relBackup
End Sub
```

Then, when replacing a table in VBA, do the following

```
dim collRelationBackup As Collection
Set collRelationBackup = DeleteRelationsCreateBackup("MyTable")
'Delete MyTable here 
'Then make sure you create a drop-in replacement with the right field names and field types for the relation to be created
RestoreRelationBackup collRelation
```

As you can see, often clearing the table and appending it is more easy, but this can be a problem with referential integrity (other tables might be cleared as well), or changes in table structure. Make sure that when you use this code, all the required fields for all the relations are there after your table has been replaced, else you will run into a runtime error and those relations will be gone.

Dependent on if you have multiple relationships with referential integrity, you might first want to duplicate the relationships of all involved tables (you can put those in a collection), then do all the deleting and replacing of tables, and then restore all of them,

Comment: Do you think is possible to use ADO.NET in VBA to overcome the problem of relationships?

Comment: No such thing as ADO.NET in VBA, just ADO. But I've just shown you VBA code that can overcome the usual problems with importing datasets with relationships. Obviously, it can be done. Do some research, try some things, and come back and ask if you have a specific problem (with example code on  what went wrong).